# How to insert (not save or update) RDD into Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, apache-spark

I am working with [Apache Spark](https://spark.apache.org/) and [Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/), and I want to save my RDD to Cassandra with [spark-cassandra-connector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector).

Here's the code:

```
def saveToCassandra(step: RDD[(String, String, Date, Int, Int)]) = {
  step.saveToCassandra("keyspace", "table")
}
```

This works fine most of the time, but overrides data that's already present in the db. I would like not to override any data. Is it somehow possible ?

Comment: Do you have a way to decide what data needs to be saved?

Comment: I believe you have similar question as this one :
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41307386/how-to-insert-rows-into-cassandra-if-they-dont-exist-using-spark-cassandra-dri/48985224#48985224](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41307386/how-to-insert-rows-into-cassandra-if-they-dont-exist-using-spark-cassandra-dri/48985224#48985224)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I do is this:

```scala
rdd.foreachPartition(x => connector.WithSessionDo(session => {
  someUpdater.UpdateEntries(x, session)
  // or
  x.foreach(y => someUpdater.UpdateEntry(y, session))
}))
```

The `connector` above is `CassandraConnector(sparkConf)`.

It's not as nice as a simple `saveToCassandra`, but it allows for a fine-grained control.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better to use WithSessionDo outside the foreach partition instead. There's overhead involved in that call that need not be repeated.