# How to insert rows into cassandra if they don't exist using spark- cassandra driver?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I want to write to cassandra from a data frame and I want to exclude the rows if a particular row is already existing (i.e Primary key- though upserts happen I don't want to change the other columns) using spark-cassandra connector. Is there a way we can do that?

Thanks.!

Comment: could you post a data sample of what you expect? The explanation is not completely clear.

Comment: For example, if my primary key is (x,y) then we need to skip the row with the same primary key while we are inserting a data frame to cassandra?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the ifNotExists `WriteConf` option which was introduced in [this pr](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/pull/967).

It works like so:

```
val writeConf = WriteConf(ifNotExists = true)
rdd.saveToCassandra(keyspaceName, tableName, writeConf = writeConf)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
sparkConf.set("spark.cassandra.output.ifNotExists", "true")
```

With this config 
if `partition key and clustering column are same as row which exists in cassandra`: 
  `write will be ignored` 
else `write will be performed`

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/insert_r.html#reference_ds_gp2_1jp_xj__if-not-exists

https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/reference.md#write-tuning-parameters

Answer (score 0):

Srinu, this all boils down to "read before write" no matter whether you are using Spark or not.

But there is `IF NOT EXISTS` clause:

> If the column exists, it is updated. The row is created if none
>   exists. Use IF NOT EXISTS to perform the insertion only if the row
>   does not already exist. Using IF NOT EXISTS incurs a performance hit
>   associated with using Paxos internally. For information about Paxos,
>   see Cassandra 2.1 documentation or Cassandra 2.0 documentation.

http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/insert_r.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply.! Yeah, my primary motto is to migrate the data, performance is not a criteria so I'm looking for a way to insert records which doesn't exist in C*.

Comment: I'm looking for the solution how can it be done using a dataframe writing it to C* using spark-C* driver.